# How to save user details while updating the iOS App?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have two sqlite databases namely workout5.sqlite3 and custom_ios.sqlite3. I copy both the databases to user directory on installation

```
if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: dbPath) {
    let fromPath: String? = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)
    var error : NSError?
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: fromPath!, toPath: dbPath)
    } 
    catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }

    let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    if (error != nil) {
        alert.title = "Error Occured"
        alert.message = error?.localizedDescription
    } 
    else {
        alert.title = "Successfully Copy"
        alert.message = "Your database copy successfully"
    }
}
```

On Installation, I check whether the file exists or not. But each time when I update the app, the databases gets replaced. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Even after updating the app to newer version, the data in documents directory, in library directory etc all remains as it is. You must be doing something wrong, otherwise if db will be there, it will not copy once again

Comment: Can you please show us the value of `dbPath`? And how its set?

Comment: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

Comment: The value of dbPath is "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7AF85A04-07DE-4F8B-A0F8-2B11C4C08609/Documents/workout5.sqlite3"

Comment: I uninstalled and installed again. This time dbPath is "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FAB734F8-8FDD-43A7-9A40-D632F59D9710/Documents/workout5.sqlite3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents directory will deleted only when the App is uninstalled. Check if readable file exist at path: `isReadableFile(atPath:)`.

Here is sample code:

```
let DBNAME = "myDB.sqlite"
let yourOriginalDatabasePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath ?? "").appendingPathComponent(DBNAME)
let pathsToDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let dbPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathsToDocuments[0]).appendingPathComponent(DBNAME)
print("dataBasebPath: \(dbPath.absoluteString)")

let isFileExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbPath.absoluteString)
let isReadableFileExist = FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: dbPath.absoluteString)
if !isReadableFileExist && !isFileExist {
     print("[DB] Copying DB to Documents Folder")
     do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: yourOriginalDatabasePath, to: dbPath)
     } catch {
        print("Fail to copy database from \(yourOriginalDatabasePath) to \(dbPath). Error: \(error)")
     }
}
```

Comment: Each time when I run my application, the dbPath values are different. For 1st time I got ("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/357C7124-7086-4954-8569-593BEB42F10D/Documents/workout5.sqlite3"), second time i got(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FAB734F8-8FDD-43A7-9A40-D632F59D9710/Documents/workout5.sqlite3)

Comment: Are you running in Simulator? or device?

Comment: I am running in Device. But its not getting copied, it went to else statement for !fileExists. But why the names are different?

Comment: iOS 8 onwards, Absolute url to app's sandbox changes every time you relaunch the app. But the same file will be there.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will try your solution and let you know

Comment: Once the file has been copied, you have to delete the app and reinstall to execute `!fileExists`.